# Disk is likely to fail soon

Tags: hard-drive

A couple weeks ago I received that warning about the disk being likely to fail soon. I ran smartctl and got the following: [results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mzWm3MbYT3/)

As you can see, it claims that my drive has actually passed the test. Also the disk utility no longer claims that my disk is going to fail but it does show a serious amount of bad sectors.

[image]

What I want to know is: Is my hard drive really going to fail soon?

P/s: I'm running Ubuntu on my Mac because I kept having boot problems with the original OS. Also, recently I had some problems copying a file which prompt the following error:

```
Error splicing file: Input/output error.
```

I bring this up because some have mentioned it indicates problems with the drive.

Comment: Yes, your drive shows hardware errors. The system currently can work around them. Is that bad? That depends on the amount of risk you are prepared to take. In any case, make backups. Keep an eye on the number of bad sectors. Find out what it would take (money and time) to replace the disk.

Comment: It can last a few months or a year or it can fail at any time without warning.  Back up your data and replace the drive

Comment: Probably a good time to start getting SSD prices. You'll love the speed increase!